# Reverse<> and Reverse

Tags: c#, reverse

I have a question about reversing the elements of a list in C#.

The ultimate goal is to get the last N elements of a list.

Suppose I have a list of decimals.

```
List<decimal> listOfDecimals = new List<decimal>() { 1.5m, 2.4m, 3.6m, 0.1m };
```

This is my attempt to get a list containing the last 2 elements of listOfDecimals.

```
List<decimal> listOfLastTwoElements = listOfDecimals.Reverse<decimal>().Take<decimal>(2).Reverse<decimal>().ToList<decimal>();
```

My question is, if I replaced Reverse<>() with Reverse(), there is a syntax error as flagged by VS.

Can anyone please let me know when I should use Reverse(), and when to use Reverse<>()?

Comment: You can simply do `var v = listOfDecimals.Skip(listOfDecimals.Count -2).ToList();`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Thanks for the suggestion. But can you also let me know when I should use one over the other?

Comment: Also, if you want to disambiguate between the `Enumerable.Reverse<T>` extension and `List<T>.Reverse`, using the `AsEnumerable<T>` extension would make the syntax clearer. E.g., `listOfDecimals.AsEnumerable().Reverse().Take(2).Reverse().ToList();`. That way, you don't have to specify the generic type parameter `<decimal>` over and over again.

Answer (score 9):

This is because List itself has a [Reverse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This reverse method does not return anything.

The reverse method on `List<T>` takes precedence over the extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`. 
Confusing is that when you just have an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use `Reverse()` without type argument. Then the type inference of the compiler resolves the generic type argument. So the extension method looks the same as the method on `List<T>`.

```
var reversed1 = Enumerable.Empty<int>().Reverse(); // works
var reversed2 = Enumerable.Empty<int>().Reverse<int>(); // works and is the same as the line above.

var reversed3 = new List<int>().Reverse(); // does not work
var reversed4 = new List<int>().Reverse<int>(); // works
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse() is a method of `List<T>`, `Reverse<T>()` is a (extension)method of `IEnumerable<T>`, so that includes `List<T>`.

If you want to take the last 2 elements of an IEnumerable, you can just do `Last(2)`. This will return an `IEnumerable<T>`, so if you want that in a List, you must call `ToList` on that.

```
List<T> also has a method `RemoveRange()`, so if you want to remove all but the last 2 elements:

listOfDecimals.RemoveRange(0, listOfDecimals.Count - 2)
```